# Column Positioning Changes When CSS Codes are Transferred to External Stylesheet

Tags: css, stylesheet

Everything works well when the CSS codes are internal (on the same page as the HTML codes). But when I transfer the CSS codes for the `spans` to the external stylesheet, the 2nd to 5th columns are positioned lower than the first column.

Here are the CSS codes:

```
.col {
      margin-top:10px;
      width:20%;
      float:left;
     }
.col li {
      font-size:9px;
      padding:10px 10px 10px 0px;
      border-bottom:1px solid #f6f4e7;
      line-height:15px;
     }
.col li:hover {
      background:#f7f3e3;
     }
.first span {
      background:url(http://website/image1) no-repeat left;
      padding:10px 0;
      padding-left:35px;
      }
.second span {
      background:url(http://website/image2) no-repeat left;
      padding:10px 0;
      padding-left:35px;
      }
.third span {
      background:url(http://website/image3) no-repeat left;
      padding:10px 0;
      padding-left:35px;
      }
.fourth span {
      background:url(http://website/image4) no-repeat left;
      padding:10px 0;
      padding-left:35px;
      }
.fifth span {
      background:url(http://website/image5) no-repeat left;
      padding:10px 0;
      padding-left:35px;
      }
```

Here are the HTML codes:

```
<ul class="col">
     <li class="first"><span><a href="/page1">anchor text</a></span></li>
</ul>
<ul class="col">
     <li class="second"><span><a href="/page2">anchor text</a></span></li>
</ul>
<ul class="col">
     <li class="third"><span><a href="/page3">anchor text</a></span></li>
</ul>
<ul class="col">
     <li class="fourth"><span><a href="/page4">anchor text</a></span></li>
</ul>
<ul class="col">
     <li class="fifth"><span><a href="/page5">anchor text</a></span></li>
</ul>
```

I tried replacing `ul` with `div` but it even got worse and the positioning problem is still there. It's like this:

[image: illustration]

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you have values for some of the elements elsewhere in your styling?

Comment: @jan199674 Thanks. I'm really clueless as to what it could be. The elements are totally new and I can't think of any possible conflicts. You have any possible scenario I could look into?

Comment: @jan199674 Wow. I was able to track it and that "first-child" was indeed specified to have a "margin-top:0". I thought naming it "col" would override it. What do I do without changing the value of that "first-child"?

Comment: @jan199674 I'm not sure using divs with a fixed height will solve the problem. They all have equal heights anyways and it's the positioning that's creating a prob. While I can probably solve this through position instead of float, I still want to track what it is that's creating the error.

Comment: delete the 'something:first-child* from CSS

Comment: @jan199674 It seems to apply to other parts of the site. If I delete it just to fix this part, the other parts could suffer. How can I disconnect this first col from being first-child?

Comment: @jan199674 finally got it solved. I simply added "!important" after the specified top-margin for "col". thanks for the tip re first-child

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65734/discussion-between-sandyaaj-and-jan199674).

Comment: Most likely a specificity issue - most likely the place where you're importing it is before the place where you had the inline styles. As a result, you could either hold off loading the CSS document (by placing further down in the header) or make the selectors affected more specific. For methodology on how to do that, [this article](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) may help